# Does This System Of Electric Charges Violate Conservation Of Energy?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, energy-conservation

Imagine a system of 3 point charges and some kind of circular "rail".

All charges have the same magnitude - 2 are positive and one negative.

One positive charge is placed at some distance from the center of the circular rail.

The two other, are "glued" together so they must move together, and they are placed on the rail which

force them to move only on the rail path.

Now imagine i give them a slight push.

Calling the glued charges the "system", We can say that the force between the system and the positive charge outside the rail is both attractive and repulsive (depending on what part of the rail the system is) but we can identify that the Parallel component of the force (with respect to the velocity vector) will always be in the direction of motion.

Thinking it through, i think you will agree that the charges on the rail will accelerate every 1 period -

therefore "generating" energy !

Can you spot what's "wrong" here ?

[image]

In this figure i used rectangular charges just to make it more clear, The "Paradox" is of course about point charges.

Comment: Won't the circled charge accelerate?

Comment: @garyp Because it's fixed. Bolted down. Nailed. Glued... whatever.

Answer (score 3):

In the bottom position, if there is some space between the two charges the positive charge at the bottom will push the positive charge away and attract the negative charge. This tends to push the two charges clockwise.

At the top the negative charge will be pulled towards fixed positive charge, while the positive charge will be repelled, so the force is anticlockwise. The force at the sides is weak because there is a force on both charges, but one there will be a greater force on the charge closer to the fixed charge. Again the force is anticlockwise.

So the moving charges will be speeding up at the top and sides, but decelerating at the bottom. I expect that they would all balance out over a full cycle.

Comment: Define "sides".
from the common definition, sides are overlap with "top" and "bottom" so your answer is not well-defined.

Comment: The deceleration will occur during the time between the negative charge in the moving pair passing the imaginary line joining the fixed positive charge to the centre of the track, and the positive charge in the moving pair passing the same imaginary line. Top, bottom and sides follows the usual convention when discussing a plan diagram, of referring to the paper held vertically or at an angle, in the normal orientation for reading. Actually at the top the negative will be attracted and the positive repelled, so it is only at the bottom they slow down. I will amend my answer appropriately.

Comment: This is pretty much it.. I expanded my answer below to include some of the ideas you brought in. BTW, _if there is some space between the two charges_ - there has to be! If not, they cancel out and there's no charge at all!

Comment: @OscarBravo, perhaps "some space" spoken like "some pig" (Charlotte's Web)

Answer (score 0):

You are imagining that the little blocks behave like positive charges when looked at one way, but then when they turn around, they become negative charges.

Actually, they would behave like dipoles. At any position on the ring, the positive end will have a repulsion force and the negative end will have an attractive force. In the general case, the two forces will be slightly different in magnitude and direction (because of the physical size of the dipole, the two ends have different displacement vectors from the source charge).

If you plot the resultant vector as a function of angular position around the ring, you will find that it can point in any direction; sometimes it has a clock-wise component and sometimes anti-clockwise. For example, at the 6 o'clock and 12 o'clock position, the resultant is tangential and clock-wise (so going against the assumed motion). In the region of 1, 5 and 7 and 11 o'clock, the resultant is radial so not affecting the rotation. At other times the vector is in various directions. Symmetry alone is enough to tell you that there will be no net force after one orbit.

The effect of all of this is that the dipoles have a rollercoaster ride around the ring - sometimes they are accelerated, sometimes decelerated, sometimes coasting. There will be stable and unstable equilibrium positions.

So if launched, your rig would orbit in a raggedy manner until friction stopped it.

Comment: Can you point out on a specific place on track where the system will decelerate and prove it ?

Also, I don't understand how do you infer the tangential force will be "backwards" based on torque considerations.
Please make your answer as rigorous as possible.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @O.Orenstein 6 o'clock and 12 o'clock. I've re-written my answer to try to explain it a bit better... BTW, if I'm wrong, build yourself a free-energy machine and make $$$millions!

Comment: Actually, at 12 o'clock they accelerate.
Anyway, Indicating deceleration at 6 o'clock is enough to break the qualitative statement "they accelerate at every point" which is the core of the seemingly paradox.
Thanks.

Comment: @O.Orenstein Check the 12 o'clock situation again: The OP has "accelerate" = "orbiting anti-clockwise". In the 6 o'clock position, the resultant is to the left, so clockwise,so decelerating. In the 12 o'clock position, the resultant is to the right, but since we are on the opposite side of the circle, that's still clockwise, so still decelerating. PS - an up-vote would be appreciated...

Comment: Imagine a moment in time where the negative charge is at 12 o'clock and the positive charge is somewhere between 12 o'clock and 3 o'clock.
Neglecting internal forces, the force on the negative charge is exactly in the radial direction, and the force on the positive charge has positive tangential component which means the system will accelerate.

I Can't emphasize how i am strongly frustrated with the saying : "accelerate" = "torque anti-clockwise", I cant see why it's true, and i have asked you for an explanation but did not receive one.
Anyway, I deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: Also, read Peter's answer, he is also saying there is acceleration at the top (i.e 12 o'clock).

Comment: @O.Orenstein By "12 o'clock" I mean the mid-point of the dipole is precisely at 12 o'clock (not the -ve charge at 12, with the +ve end trailing a bit...) If you take that highly symmetrical situation, it should be easy to see that the -ve charge (on the left) is pulled down and to the right, and that the +ve charge is pushed up and to the right. The up/down components cancel and the resultant force is to the right. Getting pushed to the right at 12 o'clock is a clockwise torque. This is contrary to the OP's original desire, which is to rotate anti-clockwise.